# C++ book recommendation- Scientific computing and C++

Tags: c++, reference-request

I'm a master's student in Math interested in Numerical Analysis. I know there are lots of questions like that on this site, but I think this is the best place to ask. So, I'm looking for an introductory book to C++ with a focus on scientific computing.

Let me clarify my situation: I've been an intensive Matlab user and I also can program quite well with Python. I can build and use myself simple classes for numerical methods and I know the basics of OOP. But, due to the performance issues, my professor told me to start learning C++ and I really want to learn it.

So, **I think I need a book which is both introductory to the language and both aimed at scientific computing/numerical analysis**, but I don't know how to choose it, because just by looking on the internet I can't make a decision on my own.

Comment: Check this one https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511812583 bit old but still useful.

Comment: Thanks! I also purchased this book, it's pretty good for my purposes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an excellent book with clear definitions and basic OOP example applied to numerical methods:

- [Daoqi Yang, *C++ and Object-Oriented Numeric Computing for Scientists and Engineers*, Springer, 2001.](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4613-0189-9) [(Amazon link)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387989900)

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking at this book now :)

Comment: Unless this book has been updated, it misses the C++11/14/17 standards, which make your life a whole lot easier. You can not said to have learned C++ these days from a book that does not at least use C++11.